# I need merger and help with account access

Tags: support, status-completed

I have the following accounts, I seem to have found out:

At math-overflow

https://mathoverflow.net/users/37385/frode-bj%C3%B8rdal

https://mathoverflow.net/users/30107/frode-bj%C3%B8rdal

(At tex-exchange

https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/24406/user24406

At physics

https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/31950/user24406

At philosophy

https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/users/5731/user24406)

If the accounts at tex, physics and philosophy are irrelevant to my problem here, please disregard that parenthetical information.

My two math-overflow accounts are connected with the same email address, and I can for inadvertent reasons no longer access the one listed first here which is the one I prefer to use. Could you please merge the two Mathoverflow accounts under the first listed here, and help me with access details and if need be by sending information I should need to frode.bjordal@ifikk.uio.no?

Comment: I've contacted someone on the StackExchange team about this. It might take a day or two for the merger request to be fulfilled.

Comment: Thank you for that!

Comment: @ Todd Trimble There seems to have occurred a less than satisfying merger as only the physics exchange gives me access. It may perhaps be because user Tim Post just went ahead and did something. What should I do? I am now back from a longer travel and would like to attend some communication at Mathoverflow, but cannot log in.

Answer (score 3):

You're all set :) If you need a merge in the future, [contact us](https://mathoverflow.net/contact) and fill in the fields that ask for the profiles that need to be merged. We *generally* have a 24 hour turnover time for support requests, sometimes a tad longer, but never more than a day or two.

The form will ask you to change your profile on the account you want to keep to say 'merge keep', and the one you want merged in (this essentially gets absorbed by the one you're keeping) to say 'merge delete'. If you can't access the profiles, don't worry too much, we can generally compare the non-public information to ascertain your ownership of both accounts.

This was a *very* clear case, so I just went ahead and did it.

Comment: The problem is that I am not satisfied with how this works. I attempted to log in to the mentioned sites, and things do not work for me now that I again have time to attend to these matters after being away.

Comment: @FrodeBjørdal Have you contacted us? That's the best way to get anything sorted, because we're probably going to need to ask you about some details that are better suited for private discussion. I'm sure whatever is going on will be simple to fix.